# Terraform: Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression

Tags: terraform

I have data file site24x7IPs.json, it looks like below:

> ```
> {
>     "LocationDetails": [
>         {
>             "IPv6_Address_External": "2803:eb80:4000:d::0/64",
>             "City": "Buenos Aires",
>             "Place": "Argentina",
>             "external_ip": "170.78.75.88"
>         },
>         {
>             "IPv6_Address_External": "",
>             "City": "Buenos Aires",
>             "Place": "Argentina",
>             "external_ip": "170.78.75.87"
>         },
>         {
>             "IPv6_Address_External": "",
>             "City": "Melbourne",
>             "Place": "Australia",
>             "external_ip": "103.91.166.0/24"
>         },
>         {
>             "IPv6_Address_External": "2400:fa80:5:9:d68e:c0c1:fced:a31a",
>             "City": "Perth",
>             "Place": "Australia",
>             "external_ip": "103.77.234.74"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Below is part of my terraform main.tf

> ```
> locals {
>   site24x7IPs = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/site24x7IPs.json"))
> }
>
> locals {
>   ipList = [for i in local.site24x7IPs.LocationDetails: i.external_ip if i.Place == "Australia"]
>   cidrList = [ for j in local.ipList: length(regexall("/", j)) <= 0 : "${j}/32" : j ]
> }
> ```

My expectation:

> cidrList = [ "103.91.166.0/24",  "103.77.234.74/32" ]

Error:

> Error: Invalid 'for' expression
>
> on main.tf line 7, in locals:    7:   cidrList = [ for j in
> local.ipList: length(regexall("/", j)) <= 0 : "${j}/32" : j ]
>
> Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

The correct syntax is:

```
 cidrList = [ for j in local.ipList: 
              length(regexall("/", j)) <= 0 ? "${j}/32" : j ]
```

but you are using double `:`, instead of `?` and ':'.

#### Previous answer

Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, it seems to be that you are after something as follows:

```
 cidrList = [ for j in local.ipList: 
              {"${j}/32" : j } if length(regexall("/", j)) <= 0  ]
```

which would give:

```
[
  {
    "103.77.234.74/32" = "103.77.234.74"
  },
]
```

or

```
 cidrList = [ for j in local.ipList: 
              "${j}/32" if length(regexall("/", j)) <= 0  ]
```

which gives:

```
[
  "103.77.234.74/32",
]
```

Comment: Thanks Marci. I found many posts said for loop support <condition> ? <true value> : <false value>, and I tried it like above, but it never succeeded. My terraform version: Terraform v0.13.4

Comment: @user2920375 I updated the answer with the correct syntax.